Google Apps script function to convert color names to hex codes
I'm trying to convert color names into appropriate hex strings for a google calendar apps script I'm building. The idea is it should take "pink puppy class" and create a calendar whose color is Pink, or whatever.
So far I'm doing the brute force approach as originally posted in Javascript function to convert color names to hex codes, since I only need a dozen or so color names, but I liked the alternate methods, especially the elegant looking answer by JayB.
But I'm unable to transmorgrify
function standardize_color(str){
    var ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle = str;
    return ctx.fillStyle;
}

Into something that google's jscript will work with. Can anybody help me here, or point me in a new direction?

It would be nice to have W3's 140 color names available with the click of a function...

Google script can not convert a string color name to hex, it needs a "background" object. So, something like in https://spreadsheet.dev/how-to-get-the-hexadecimal-codes-of-colors-in-google-sheets will be the best approach.
